# Vectorize thinking

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I'm having a vectorization problem. Say I'm having a vector `x <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0)` , what I want is to get the vector `(1,0,1,1)`, or to remove all the 0s from the first spot to the first non-zero spot and all the 0s from last non-zero spot to the last spot. It is easy in normal ways, but the tricky part is I cannot use any loops (for, while, etc). Basically, I must "vectorize" the whole algorithm. Anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try this,
Thanks for `@JacobH` comment, this will be faster.

```
x <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0)
zeros <- which(x > 0)

x[zeros[1]:tail(zeros, n = 1)]
```

the output

> [1] 1 0 1 1

Comment: Minor change to Zihu Guo's approach.  Initialize the call to which.  i.e. `zeros=which(x > 0); x[zeros[1]:tail(zeros, n=1)]`

Comment: My addition does make it more readable.  However, its importance is much more fundamental than that.  In @Zihu Guo original post the which function is called twice.  This results in unnecessary calculations.  Consequently, my addition will result in faster code.

Comment: `@JacobH` thank you for your comment, you are right. I have changed the code.

Comment: @JacobH You guys might be interested in the comparison I just added (as another answer). `which` is slow for this task because it looks at every element. It is faster to stop at the first nonzero result.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if speed is a concern, just use loops:

```
x <- rpois(1e8,1)
# Zihu Guo & JacobH's answer
system.time({zeros <- which(x > 0); x[zeros[1]:tail(zeros, n = 1)]})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.46    0.42    1.89 

# a slightly improved version of their answer
system.time({zeros <- which(!!x); x[zeros[1]:tail(zeros, n = 1)]})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.21    0.42    1.64 


system.time({
    lo  = 0L
    lov = 0L
    while (!lov){ lo = lo+1L ; lov = lov+x[lo] }
    hi  = length(x)+1L
    hiv = 0L
    while (!hiv){ hi = hi-1L ; hiv = hiv+x[hi] }    
    x[lo:hi]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.62    0.07    0.71
```

Besides speed, this is nice because it requires no real knowledge of R. It could be made faster with the `Rcpp` package, probably.

(If the whole vector is zeros, this will never terminate. Small adjustments can be made if that matters. If the vector is *mostly* zeros, the `which` method is faster. For example, consider `x <- rep(0L,1e8); x[1e8/2] <- 1L`.)

Comment: hmmm.. I'm guessing `:` is the bottle neck, probably `seq.int` will be preferable.

Comment: @DavidArenburg The timing is similar with that change on my comp. Maybe negative indexing is better...lemme check.

Comment: The idea: construction of `lo:hi` might be costlier than its complement. For most `rpois` samples with lamba = 1, almost nothing is dropped.

Comment: Great example Frank.  The reason your approach is faster is because it is usually the case that it is faster to loop over the first zero entries of a vector than do a vectorized operation over the entire vector.  This will not always be that case.  Imagine that you have a vector of length 1e8, and the first 9e7 entries are zero.  I suspect that Zihu Guo's approach is faster in such a scenario.  So let your priors about your problem guide your programming strategy.

Comment: @JacobH Yeah, good point. With `x <- rep(0L,1e8); x[1e8/2] <- 1L` mine takes ages.